# Excel VBA How to locate variable number of detail lines between header and totals row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to locate categories, along with the detail lines of the category, and the total row of the category. There are a variable number of detail lines in each category. I need to copy the detail lines to another workbook.This code 'works' but I think there is a better way to do it.

The data looks like this, sample data...(each line is a row)

```
BlankLine  
Contract Labor  
Vendor  
detail line  
detail line  
detail line  
Contract Labor Totals  
blank line  
blank line  
Hardware Maintenance  
Vendor  
detail line  
detail line  
detail line  
detail line  
Hardware Maitenence Totals
```

This is the code I have so far...

```
'Locate first cell downwards with a category name 
Set currentCell = currentCell.End(xlDown)
'Set the category name
categoryName = currentCell.Value
notFoundCategory = True
'Set the search string to the category name + Totals
searchStr = currentCell.Value & " Totals"
'Set the current Row for tracking
cRow = currentCell.Row
'Loop until searchStr is found, incrementing currentCell by 1 row until the searchStr is found
    Do While notFoundCategory = True
        If currentCell.Value = searchStr Then
            notFoundCategory = False
            Set currentCell = currentCell.Offset(1, 0)
            'Check to see if currentCell.Value has a Vendorname
        ElseIf (currentCell.Value) <> "Vendor" And (currentCell.Value) <> categoryName Then
            'Process detail rows
            Set currentCell = currentCell.Offset(1, 0)
        Else
            Set currentCell = currentCell.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Loop
```

Please pardon if there is a post about this already. I did search for it but was unable to find it.

Comment: it's impossible to guess what you are trying to achieve without seeing your data, share a screen-shot of your sheet, and your desired result

Comment: Updated sample data with proper formatting

Comment: Most of your code seems fine to me, the only thing you can improve is instead of increment `currentCell` by 1 using  `currentCell.Offset(1, 0)`, you can jump directly to the next line using `Application.Match` , if that's something that will interest you

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues that I would address:

1. currentCell.End(xlDown) will go all the way down your spreadsheet 
   after the last row with data in it potentially resulting in a
   needless error never mind having to wait for it to do so.
2. As your sample data highlights, if you have a typo in
   the 'Totals' row as you do with 'Hardware Maitenence',
   your macro will process all the remaining rows in your
   worksheet as detail rows - which is definitely not what
   you want to have happen.

Given that you're using a range variable to go down your worksheet, I'd do the following instead:

```
'Put these somewhere at the top of your outer loop
Dim lastCell As Range, foundCell As Range
Set lastCell = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, currentCell.Column).End(xlUp)

'Where your posted code starts off from:

'Locate first cell downwards with a category name
Set currentCell = Range(currentCell, lastCell).Find(what:="*", _
                    after:=currentCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas)
If currentCell = lastCell Then
  'You are at the end of all your data so exit normally
  Exit Sub
End If

'Set the category name
categoryName = currentCell.Value
'Set the search string to the category name + Totals
searchStr = currentCell.Value & " Totals"

'Look for search string
Set foundCell = ExactlyMatched(searchStr, Range(currentCell, lastCell))
If foundCell Is Nothing Then
  'Fatal Error Message
  MsgBox ("Could not find: " & searchStr)
  Exit Sub 'or stop execution here
End If

'See whether you have a 'Vendor' row or not
If currentCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "Vendor" Then
  'Equivalent to printing a warning message
  Debug.Print "no Vendor found for " & categoryName
  Set currentCell = currentCell.Offset(2, 0)
Else
  Set currentCell = currentCell.Offset(1, 0)
End If

'Process all the detail rows
Do While currentCell <> foundCell
  'Process Detail Row
  Set currentCell = currentCell.Offset(1, 0)
Loop
Set currentCell = currentCell.Offset(2, 0)
```

And add the following function somewhere in your module:

```
Function ExactlyMatched(val As String, valRng As Range) As Range
  Dim rowOffset As Integer
  On Error GoTo ErrHandler

  rowOffset = Application.Match(val, valRng, 0)
  Set ExactlyMatched = valRng(1, 1).Offset(rowOffset - 1, 0)
  Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    Set ExactlyMatched = Nothing
End Function
```

If you don't find the searchStr that's a fatal error for which you immediately notify the user and stop processing.  Also if you have don't have a 'Vendor' line right after the categoryName row, you can issue a warning to the Immediate Window but continue on processing as this isn't an error but something that the user might want to know.

Comment: Thank you. That is very helpful.